# Keras - Retrieve layers that the layer connected to

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I have a model built in Keras that can be sequential or functional. Model is accessible through the `model` variable. I want to implement the method that would walk through the model from the output to the input and do something with the weights of the model.

Is there any way to get a predecessor layer of the specific layer? I would like to do something like this:

```
x = <some number>
layer_x = model.layers[x] 
predecessor_layers = ???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution suggested by @Mitiku returns only the input tensor but we need a predecessor layer. Predecessor layer can be found following way:

```
x = <some number>
layer_x = model.layers[x] 
int_node = layer_x._inbound_nodes[0]
predecessor_layers = int_node.inbound_layers[0]
```

In the proposed solution, we assume that the `layer_x` has only one predecessor layer. To get that layer we first access to the node which connects those two layers: `int_node` and then takes the layer which is on its input: `int_node.inbound_layers[0]`.

Note: This solution is not nice since it access to the protected attribute but it works.

Comment: @rob thank you for the update. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about `_inbound_nodes` being changed (unless you are using `model.get_config()`). E.g. you can call `model.get_config()['layers'][0]['inbound_nodes']` or `model.layers[0]._inbound_nodes` to get the inbound nodes. Deleting my previous comment

Comment: There is a typo in the `_inbound_nodes` (you forgot the `_`). I can't edit since it's less than 6 characters.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without accessing protected attributes? It is mind-boggling to me that there is no easy way of accessing the model architecture.